# Specify FFDC filename

Tags: open-liberty

Anybody know of a way to specify which filename to use for ffdc logs and summary?
I have tried to specify the environment variable `com.ibm.ffdc.log` with no effect. I am using OpenLiberty 19.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This variable is used in WebSphere traditional (8.5.5/9.0).

OpenLiberty logging configuration is described here - https://openliberty.io/docs/21.0.0.6/log-trace-configuration.html

In Liberty you can change the output and log folder locations.
You can also combine messages from various sources via properties or env variables. For example:

```
WLP_LOGGING_MESSAGE_FORMAT=json
WLP_LOGGING_MESSAGE_SOURCE=message,trace,accessLog,ffdc,audit
```

Any reasons why you need to change ffdc filename/location?

Comment: Hi @gas thanks for answering. We need to integrate with a rather antiquated monitoring solution that trigger alarms when something gets written to specific files. Application logs are handled by Log4j, but it would be nice to also monitor the FFDC logs.

Comment: So if you dont mind json format, then you can redirect all sources to `message.log` and change the its name via `server.xml` property `messageFileName` or `bootstrap.properties` -  `com.ibm.ws.logging.message.file.name`